# In the output HTML, how to embed an HTML file that embeds scss and js

Tags: webpack

I am successfully embedding different html file using the `html-webpack-plugin` like this:

```
<%= require('html!./path/partial.html') %>
```

But inside that file I have added some CSS inline within `<style>` tags and some JavaScript within `<script>` tags.

I would ultimately prefer to somehow extract the styles in a different `scss` file and the scripts inside different es6 `js` file. Then I'd like to embed them in the `partial.html` using their appropriate loaders.

**Note:** These styles and scripts are only used within `partial.html`.

How do I achieve this?

```
index.html
partial/
  partial.html
  partial.scss
  partial.js
```

Comment: did you figure out answer for this ?